# Ai spins all the time when collision occurs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, artificial-intelligence, collision-detection

Have a simple AI thats follows the player when in range and randomly moves the ai around when it's not in the player range. When the AI hits a wall and is out of the players range it starts to spin all the time. Can't work out why it keeps doing so.

I may be missing a simple thing...
Many thanks for any help.

```
void Update()
{
    Target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");

    if (Vector3.Distance(Target.transform.position, transform.position) < 25)
    {
        followPlayer();
    }
    else
    {
        randomMovement();
    }

}

public void followPlayer()
{

    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Target.transform.position) >= MinDist)
    {

        transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.LookAt(Target.transform);


        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Target.transform.position) <= MaxDist)
        {
        }

    }
    else
    {

    }

}

public void randomMovement()
{
    transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.Rotate(RandomDirection * Time.deltaTime * 10.0f);

}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    bool hasTurned = false;

    if (col.transform.gameObject.name != "Terrain")
    {
        if(hasTurned == false)
        {
            RandomDirection = new Vector3(0, Mathf.Sin(TimeBetween) * (RotationRange / 2) + OriginalDirection, 0);
            randomMovement();
            hasTurned = true;
        }
        else
        {
            randomMovement();
            hasTurned = false;
        }


        Debug.Log("Hit");
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a rigidbody attached to your AI Entity? That is probably causing the spin after the collision. If so, try to freeze the rotation. Have a look at : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-freezeRotation.html It is also possible, that it looks like its spinning, cause you it keeps entering a collision with the wall, cause you  chose a pretty random rotation and let it move, instead of having an "intelligent" way to get away from an obstacle

Comment: Yes I do, that may be the cause of the issue! Thanks @TobiasTheel

Comment: If you can confirm, that this was really the cause, i'll create an answer for that :)

Comment: Unfortunately no, still spins... Will have to think of an intelligent way to move the player away before checking again. @TobiasTheel

Comment: A pretty "dumb" solution could be to let the AI just walk into the oposite direction on colission. As you don't seem to use PathFinding it could be a temporary fix.

Comment: Would then just do up and down. Am going to implement pathfinding in the future for now am making a basic as possible prototype to test and play with @TobiasTheel

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is continuously spinning is because you are continuously calling `randomMovement()` in your Update() which continously applies a rotation to your object with `Rotate()`. It sounds like what you are instead trying to do is have the object wander aimlessly every few seconds. You could do this by implementing on timer on your randomMovement() so that every few seconds, it generates a new rotation(similar to what you have in the onCollision). Example below.

```
float t = 0;
public void randomMovement()
{
    transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    t += Time.deltaTime;
    if (t > 3f) // set to a new rotation every 3 seconds.
    {
        t = 0; // reset timer
        RandomDirection = new Vector3(0, Random.Range(0f, 360f), 0); // turn towards random direction

        transform.Rotate(RandomDirection);
    }
}
```